# get missing date ranges in sql hana

Tags: hana

Created a table as below in sap hana and inserted some records

| date_start | date_end |
| --- | --- |
| 2014-03-05 | 2014-04-10 |
| 2014-05-01 | 2014-06-05 |
| 2014-07-10 | 2014-08-15 |
| 2014-08-16 | 2014-08-20 |

Need output for the missing date ranges for above records

| date_start | date_end |
| --- | --- |
| 2014-01-01 | 2014-03-04 |
| 2014-04-11 | 2014-04-30 |
| 2014-06-06 | 2014-07-09 |
| 2014-08-16 | 2014-12-31 |

saw a similar requirement in mysql here

[Mysql Find missing date ranges](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23949227/mysql-find-missing-date-ranges)

Regards
Prasad

Comment: Do you have a "dates" table somewhere that lists all dates in ranges you care about? Hana doesn't support recursive CTE; so we can't easily dynamically generate all dates in a 2014 year. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69829941/with-recursive-common-table-expressions-in-sap-hana

Comment: What data types are your dates string? Decimal, date...

Comment: CREATE COLUMN TABLE "d" (
 "date_start" DATE CS_DAYDATE,
 "date_end" DATE CS_DAYDATE
)

Answer (score 1):

Do you have the ability to Generate Time Data? There is native functionality in HANA to generate time series data on the _SYS_BI schema under M_TIME_DIMENSION.

You'll need privileges on that schema in order to do this.

If you're using HANA via the Web IDE then refernece https://help.sap.com/viewer/e8e6c8142e60469bb401de5fdb6f7c00/2.0.06/en-US/6b9c2d4538004ef494ff977b733aa120.html

Else you can go into Studio under the Modeler perspective and select 'Generate Time Data' under Quick View. You can then choose what Calendar Type you'd like (Gregorian I'm assuming), in addition to the level of details and number of years for which you want to generate data.